# Angular : Execute code after template style is applied

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I'm doing a basic setup such as :

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const element = document.getElementById('someList');
    this.isScrollable = element.scrollWidth > element.clientWidth;
  }
```

However, it seems the styles from my css have not been applied yet, therefore `scrollWidth` and `clientWidth` have the same value.

I also tried with `ngAfterViewChecked()`.

How can I execute my code after the style has been applied ?

Also, here is the relevant CSS (I'm using scss if that matters) :

```
#someList {
    position: relative;
    top: 220px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```